# How do I evaluate the randomness of a Java App?

Tags: java, random

I'm generating words randomly from several arrays of strings.

There are 4 arrays of lengths 7, 9, 15 and 24.

This means there are 22,680 possible permutations. To that I append a number of 0-999 to the end of the string, meaning I multiply the possible permutation by 999 for a total of over 22 million combination.

I'm using a list to evaluate the frequency of collisions and am getting some very low numbers. I never make it over 10,000 iterations before a duplicate string is found.

```
String[][] dictionary = // array of 4 string arrays
public String assemble() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(30);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        // for each strArr, select a random element
        sb.append(select(dictionary[i]));
    }
    // add a number from 0 - 999 to the end of the string
    sb.append(randInt(999));
    return sb.toString();
}

private String select(String[] strArr) {
    return strArr[randInt(strArr.length)];
}

List<String> generatedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> iterations = new ArrayList<>();
// iterate until the same string is generated twice or we make 1M strings
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    String s = assemble();
    if (generatedStrings.contains(s)) {
        iterations.add(i);
        generatedStrings.clear();
        break;
    }
    generatedStrings.add(s);
}
```

The method for generating the random integers:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
public int randInt(int length) {
    return secureRandom.nextInt(length);
    // also tried the following, though I think the underlying tech is the same: 
    // return (int) (Math.random() * length);
}
```

When I run this in a main method I'm getting numbers around 13k which seems very low. Is this an issue with the way I am generating the random numbers?

Comment: *FYI:* `randInt(999)` returns a number in range 0-998, not 0-999, but you are correct that that is 999 permutations.

Comment: True random numbers will have duplicates. You might want to look up the "birthday paradox", where statistically if you have a group of around 30 people, two people will probably have the same birthday.

Comment: 2 people with the same birthday in a group of 30 is fine.  But if we are selecting from a pool of 22 million dates what are the chances we would pick the same date in just a few thousand attempts?

Comment: Using the Birthday Paradox formula, we can then calculate that there is only **11% chance** of picking 10000 *distinct* values from a set of 22657320 values. There is only **2.4% chance** of picking 13000 values, and virtually no chance (10⁻⁹⁷²⁷%) of picking 1 million values.

Comment: How soon you see the first duplicate is, itself, a random phenomenon.  So seeing that first duplicate sooner [than you think you should] is not a sure sign of unrandomness. What counts is the amount and frequency of duplication you see overall, after a suitably large number of trials.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will use the birthday paradox formula as my starting point in evaluating what I need.

Comment: @Andreas is there a good calculator you would recommend for doing these calculations with very large numbers?

Comment: @IcedDante I used `BigDecimal` in Java code. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/od4eZF).